# Perl error in search and replace windows

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to remove tag head using regex of mutiples files recursive in windows 10 using perl

```
forfiles /s /m *.html /c "perl -pi -e s/<head(?:.|\n|\r)+?</head>//g @path"
```

but I get this message and I dont understand what I wrong

```
Illegal division by zero at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

`/` in `</head>` must be escaped with `\` because `/` is the substitute delimiter or another delimiter can be used. for example `s,<head(?:.|\n|\r)+?</head>,,g`.

also as regex seems to be multi line perl switch `-0777` can be used to unset record separator and read the whole file, otherwise input is split bynewlines before applying regex.

Comment: forfiles /s /m *.html /c "perl -pi -e s,<head(?:.|\n|\r)+?</head>,,g @path"

Comment: it may not work for many reasons what is the error? seems you missed -0777 : `perl -0777 -pi -e ...`

Comment: not given any error in terminal but doesn't work not change any file

Comment: when I tried forfiles /s /m *.html /c "perl -0777 -pi -e s,<head(?:.|\n|\r)+?</head>,,g" give this error "-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN."

Comment: this -0777 work in windows 10? this command is not for unix systems ?

Comment: no from `perl -h` `-0[octal]         specify record separator (\0, if no argument)`, however 777 is a special value which means no input record separator, -00 is another special which means "paragraph mode" input record separator is more than 2 consecutive newlines,otherwise `-0`can also be used if there is no nul byte in input file